# Apache Shiro and SSO

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, shiro

Apache Shiro is a Java security framework and support SSO. And I have multiple sub-domains, each of which has separate application running. How can I use Apache Shiro web filters(or any other) to provide single sign on.

Should I need a SSO server or service (like CAS?) before I use Apache Shiro ? Or Apache Shiro do not need SSO server or service (like CAS) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I am not Shiro expert, but I will try to help you.
According to my understanding Shiro does not provide SSO service out of the box. You need to use CAS filter as SSO service. Please look the following page that explain you how to define Shiro CasFilter: http://shiro.apache.org/cas.html

Answer (score 0):

For Shiro to support SSO, Cas is now deprecated, you need to use [buji-pac4j](https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j) library to support SSO using multiple protocols like SAML, OpenIdConnect, etc.