# How to implement SSO using CAS in shiro

Tags: jsf, active-directory, jsf-2.2, shiro

I want to implement SSO in shiro using CAS with active directory.If Anyone having experience of this implementation,please share with me. Also suggest basic requirement for this.
Many Thanks.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597274/apache-shiro-and-sso) help you

Answer (score 0):

this should help you getting started, I know that the post has a different name, but it actually contains what you need too.

http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Shiro-and-multiple-wars-within-the-same-Servlet-Container-td5560737.html#a5563334

Cheers!